# Headphones volume is turned all the way down, however I can still hear audio?

Tags: audio, headphones

I recently purchased [Plantronics .Audio 355](http://www.plantronics.com/us/product/audio-355)

I am having an issue with the volume. There's a volume adjuster on my headset, but when I turn it all the way down, I can still hear sound? The only way to completely get rid of the sound is by turning it all the way down in the volume control options. I'm wanting to be able to adjust the volume FULLY with my headset itself. (sync issue? not sure)

I've been searching around the internet but haven't found anything. Hopefully one of you can be some help. Thanks!

Comment: This is the current windows design of the audio stack. The driver of the audio device is responsible for controlling what the lowest volume is. The only way to guarantee no audio on all hardware is to mute it (not turning the volume to zero)

Comment: @BalaSivakumar, the Plantronics 335 headset uses 3.5mm analog jacks, so the volume control on this headset is just an inline potentiometer.

Answer (score 1):

Either your headset volume control is defective, or the design of the headset volume control is defective.

The volume control options in the OS is software controlled (no wires, knobs, ect).  The volume control on our headset should be hardware controlled, that is physical items that adjust the volume (knobs, resistors, potentiometers, etc) which is completely independent of your computer.  Normally, turning the volume down on a hardware type device attenuates the signal to 0db, which is 0volts and therein 0 current.  If you can still hear sound, then you volume control does not attenuate the signal like it should.  I can't imagine a volume control designed to only attenuate from loud to soft, most go to off.  Any thing other than this is a defect.

Try plugging your headset into the output of another device like a stereo receiver.  And see if it exhibits the same behavior; it should.

Talk to your supplier; ask if the other headsets of the same make and model do this as well.  If they do, buy a different one; if they do not, get a replacement.

Comment: I wonder whether the sound card or audio jack op is using is configured for high impedance headphones? Would the potentiometer in this headset be tuned for the typical low-impedance outputs on most sound cards?